# Load PHP variables into XML file

Tags: php, xml

So, what i am trying to achieve is to load variables from PHP into an XML file.

this is how my XML looks at the moment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<firstname></firstname>
<lastname></lastname>
```

And this is my PHP where i try to save the variables into the XML

```
        $file = simplexml_load_file("filename.xml");

        $xml->firstname = "Mark";

        $xml->lastname = "Zuckerberg";

        file_put_contents($file, $xml->asXML());
```

If i try to print this i get following error message:

```
Call to undefined method stdClass::asXML() in ... on line 1374
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `$file = ...` + `$xml->asXML()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't create the initial XML file, the library you are using creates it for you.

[XML DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_dom.asp) is a fine choice for this job.

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();                                  # Create a document
$xml_firstname = $xml->createElement("firstname", "Over"); # Create an element
$xml_lastname = $xml->createElement("lastname", "Coder");  # Create an element
$xml->appendChild($xml_firstname);                         # Add the element to the document
$xml->appendChild($xml_lastname);                          # Add the element to the document
$xml->save("myfancy.xml");                                 # Save the document to a file
```

The output would be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<firstname>Over</firstname>
<lastname>Coder</lastname>
```

Comment: Which gives me a "Class 'DOMDocument' not found in TestController.php on line 1360"

Comment: @MarcelWasilewski What system do you use? and if Linux, what distro?

Comment: You need to install it, if you have Ubuntu or Debian, execute `sudo apt-get install php5-dom` in your system terminal, if you have Red Hat/Fedora/Cent OS you need `yum install php-xml`

Answer (score 1):

Enable error reporting (like `error_reporting( E_ALL );`) and you will understand quickly why it does not work:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): xml.xml:3: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
// your XML is not correctly formatted (XML requires a root node)

Warning: Creating default object from empty value
// $xml->firstname when $xml does not exists
```

To resolve that, your XML should looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<data><!-- here comes the root node -->
<firstname></firstname>
<lastname></lastname>
</data>
```

And the PHP should looks like previous answers:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("filename.xml");
$xml->firstname = "Mark";
$xml->lastname = "Zuckerberg";
file_put_contents("filename_copy.xml", $xml->asXML());
```

Answer (score 0):

First off: where do you establish `$xml`?

You start with `$file = ...` but then refer to the object as `$xml`.

Either change the object name to `$xml` or change the references to `$file`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("filename.xml"); /* note the object name change */
$xml->firstname = "Mark";
$xml->lastname = "Zuckerberg";
```

---

Next, your `file_put_contents()` command is incorrect. The first parameter is accepts is the filename, however in your example `$file` is not a name but a `simplexml` object.

```
file_put_contents("path/to/file.xml", $xml->asXML());
```

Alternatively, use the `asXML()` method with the path by doing this (thanks *bassxzero*):

```
$xml->asXML("path/to/file.xml");
```

---

Finally, your script is outputting the error:

> Call to undefined method stdClass::asXML()

This implies that you can't call `$xml->axXML()` as (I'm assuming) either the method doesn't exist, or the object doesn't have the correct method.

Changing the name of the object initially (the first issue) should fix this!

Comment: instead of the file_put_contents call he could use `$xml->asXML('path/to/file.xml');`

Comment: I have done it like you mentioned above, still getting the same Error message.

Answer (score 0):

From the code, you load the XML into $file.
But you edit $xml. The below code should work

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("filename.xml");
$xml->firstname = "Mark";
$xml->lastname = "Zuckerberg";
file_put_contents("output.xml", $xml->asXML());
```